# Bridge mode: will traffic go to the router or not?

Tags: bridge

I have a timecapsule connecting to my ISP router in bridge mode.

My question is: If i'm connected to the timecapsule, and exchanging data with the router, will the traffic go to the router to come back to the time capsule, or is the timecapsule simply forwarding?

So is it:
a- device 1 -> time capsule -> router -> time capsule -> device 2
b- device 1 -> time capsule -> device 2

Obviously, I'm asking because the bandwidth differ!

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Have you searched for the information? Please read this link http://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/adsl_modem_router_bridge_mode